# Extend CKEditor Plugin with own language files

Tags: ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

We are implementing CKEditor and added the token-plugin (http://ckeditor.com/addon/token).
Sadly the token-plugin just provides two language files (en + ru).
So we need to add more languages files.

We tried it using the plugin-lang api:

```
CKEDITOR.plugins.setLang( 'token', 'de', {
    title: 'Platzhalter',
    toolbar: 'Platzhalter',
    name: '',
    pathName: 'token'
} );
```

It does not work, because the api is called too early or maybe too late.
And we don't want to extend the plugin source.

Can anyone help us?

Best regards, Gregor

Answer (score 1):

I think at the moment, it's not possible to do that (the api is not supporting it).

Maybe you can ask the plugins owner to update that.

Answer (score 0):

The quickest and most frequently used solution is to send your translations to the plugin author, either as a pull request for their source code repository or even in a comment on its [Add-ons Repository](http://ckeditor.com/addons/plugins/all) page.

Comment: This is what we did at least.

Comment: Great, thanks. You may also want to accept this as an answer to make it more obvious for other users who may find this question in the future.